# Migrating NULL Values of a Column to Another Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two column table for orders,

```
ID OPEN CLOSE
1  {}   {}
2  {}   NULL
3  {}   {}
```

`OPEN/CLOSE` columns are `JSONB` columns containing a receipt from a third party API they are not queried often only used later for analytics reasons. In order to distinguish between completed orders and still waiting orders I check the `CLOSE`column value if `NOT NULL` order is completed. However due to changes in the third party API I'll have to keep some `JSON` value in `CLOSE` column. My plan is to create a third column enum type called `STATUS` and keep track of the status of orders using this enum. My question is how to migrate data from `CLOSE` into `STATUS` every `NOT NULL`should get one enum rest another.

```
ID OPEN CLOSE  STATUS
1  {}   {}     FILLED
2  {}   NULL   WAITING
3  {}   {}     FILLED
```

Comment: Go with a generated column, to avoid data inconsistency. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: @jarlh this migration will be done once. after the update both open and close columns will be in use any system will use status column to keep track of orders from that point forward. Genrated columns will still have to rely on the fact that close column is null no?

Comment: A generated column means it will automatically be adjusted if the ClosedDate value is changed. I.e. when CLOSE is set to a non-null value, STATUS will automatically be set to FILLED.

Answer (score 0):

This fills STATUS with one of two possible values depending on CLOSE having a value or not:

```
update orders set STATUS = (case when CLOSE is null then 'WAITING' else 'FILLED' end);
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is creating a `DateTime` column named `ClosedDate`. `NULL` values in the new column will continue to be treated the same way you currently treat `NULL` values in the `Close` column; anything tells you the exact time the order closed. This will use less storage, while giving you more information at the ready.

... except of course for the existing data, where you don't have this information available via the schema. For these records, you could either break into the existing JSON data to find the value you want, or you could use an pre-determined value to mean the record was closed before the data was tracked.

So you could do something like this migrate the existing data:

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET ClosedDate = CASE WHEN Close IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CURRENT_DATE END
```

If you do proceed with a `status` field (and there is a good argument for this vs my suggestion, because it sets you up for more different order states in the future), it might be better to use shorter status codes; there's no need to store the entire word in the table. This will fit a few more records per page, and help any indexing use less memory.

Comment: My idea is to setup for more order states in the future. I am planning to use an enum not a string. when you say entire word do you mean machine word or english word? AFAIK enum will just store a numeric value while giving me english value?